# Excel formula - Remove only 'odd' positioned number strings from a concatenated cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**My request:** Excel formula to remove every ‘*even*’ positioned string of letters or numbers, contained within one cell, separated by semicolons (;) so only the ‘*odd*’ positioned number\ text strings remain.

I have some data, with a dreaded *mixed values cell*….. ahhh. I would love a formula that removes every “*other!*” string of values, from a cell made up of a series of numbers that represent “**Product codes**”.

**To elaborate:**

My problematic cells live in say column [`B`]. A typical cells content say [`B2`] looks like this: `534222;#212;#634196;#331;#538015;#75` .

In this example my “*Product codes*” are: `534222`; `#634196`; `#538015` 
…….. the random numbers I want to get rid of are: `#212`;`#331`;`#75`.  *Just to be clear, not always these numbers, they could be any number.*

I have noticed the random numbers appear between my “*Products Codes*”, and are always the *2nd, 4th, 6th …. etc*. numbers in the string.

There is no pattern to the numbers, other than their position within the overall string of values…. always *2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th etc*. i.e. in and ‘***even***’ position, with each value being separated by a semicolon (`;`) and preceded by a  hash sign (`#`).

I want my “*Product Codes*”, which seem to appear in an ‘**odd**’ ranked position *1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th etc…*. to stay and the random numbers to go.

**Extra info:**
I would still like my “Product codes” *demarcated* by a comma (`,`) or a semi-colon (`;`), not fussed about the hash sign (#), it can stay or go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
Function CleanEvenItems(value As String) As String

    spl = Split(value, ";")
    For i = 0 To UBound(spl) Step 2
        CleanEvenItems = CleanEvenItems & spl(i) & ";"
    Next

End Function
```

and use it like this

=CleanEvenItems(B2)

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following *UDF()* in a standard module:

```
Public Function KeepOdd(rin As Range) As String
   Dim Flip As Boolean
   ary = Split(rin.Text, ";")
   Flip = True
   KeepOdd = ""
   For Each a In ary
      If Flip Then
         KeepOdd = KeepOdd & ";" & a
         Flip = False
      Else
         Flip = True
      End If
   Next a

   KeepOdd = Mid(KeepOdd, 2)
End Function
```

and with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

=KeepOdd(A1)

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=KeepOdd(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**